# Why doesn't my function to swap variables swap variables?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

First, I have this function:

```
def change_pos(a, b):
  temp = a
  a = b
  b = temp
  print 'Done'
```

And I call it in another function but it just print 'Done' and do nothing.
I write the code directly:

```
a = 1
b = 2
temp = a
a = b
b = temp
```

It works fine. Any suggestion here?
Second, this is my code

```
def check_exception(list):
    for element in list:
    # Take list of numbers
    # \s*: Skip space or not (\t\n\r\f\v), \d: Number [0-9]
    # ?: Non-capturing version of regular parentheses
        first = re.compile("\s*(?:\[)(\d+)\s*(?:,)").findall(element)
        last = re.compile("\s*(?:,)(\d+)\s*(?:\])").findall(element)
    # Convert string to integer
        first_int = map(int, first)
        last_int = map(int, last)

    # Check and code above works
        i = 0
        print first_int[i]
        change_pos(first_int[i],first_int[i+1])
        print first_int[i+1]
        print len(first_int)
        #print type(first_int[0])
    # Sort
        # Error: list index out of range at line 47 and more
        i = 0
        while i < len(first_int):
            if first_int[i] > first_int[i+1]:
                change_pos(first_int[i], first_int[i+1])
                change_pos(last_int[i], last_int[i+1])
            i += 1
    # Check exception
        j = 0
        while j < len(last_int):
            if last_int[j] < first_int[j+1]:
                return false
                break
            else:
                j += 1
                continue
            return true
```

And I see: *IndexError: list index out of range* at conditions after *# Error*
Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: For the second issue, I suggest you start a new question. You shouldn't ask two questions in one question here. This prevents me from giving you a +1.

Comment: OK, I fixed it, so it's correct now. Still. Welcome to SO, but you'll probably do better of you use the site as intended. Read the FAQ etc under "help" on top.

Comment: As a side note, in Python, you don't need a temporary variable to swap two variables; just do `a, b = b, a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `change_pos` function does nothing useful as it only swaps the variables inside the function, not the variables that was used to call the function. One method of accomplishing what you want is this:

```
def change_pos(a, b):
    print 'DONE'
    return b, a
```

and then using it becomes:

```
a, b = change_pos(a,b)
```

Or even without a function:

```
a, b = b, a
```

Secondly, I'm sure you can figure out why you're getting an index error on your own. But here's why anyways. Arrays are zero indexed and you are using the length of `last_int` in your while loop. Now imagine `last_int` has a length of 5. That means it has index values ranging from 0-4. In the last iteration of the loop you are attempting to access `last_int[5]` in your if statement (`last_int[j+1]`) which of course will give you an index error.

Comment: If Python uses pass by value then the value it passes is a reference. Which means it passes by reference. ;-) In fact the distinction simply makes no sense in Python.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Yeah that's true. Same kind of odd situation with Java.

Comment: @DuongVu: Make the second question a separate question.

Comment: @btse That would still have been incorrect, it just passes references. No copying. This has nothing to do with passing, the issue is the name binding. The names are local.

Comment: @LennartRegebro The kind of "pass by value where value is a reference" is sometimes called "pass by sharing" to limit confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You may have been told that variables are locations in memory with data in it. This is not true for Python. Variables are just names that point to objects.

Hence, you can not in Python write a function such as the change_pos function you attempt to write, because the names you change will be the names used in the function, not the names used when calling.

Instead of this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
change_pos(a, b)
```

You will have to do this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
a, b = change_pos(a, b)
```

The function needs to look like this:

```
def change_pos(a, b):
    return b, a
```

This give you a hint that there is an easier way, and indeed there is. You can do this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
a, b = b, a
```

So no need for a function at all.

Since you actually want to swap integers in a list, you can make a function like this:

```
def change_pos(lst, p):
    lst[p], lst[p+1] = lst[p+1], lst[p]
```

But I don't think that adds significantly the the readability of the code.

Also your usage of this is prefixed with the comment `#sort`. But your code does not sort. It's a bit like a half-assed bubble sort, but I don't know why you would want to do that.

Comment: Yes, but I use it many times with some complex variables so I wanna write a function to make my code readable :) Thank you

Comment: Yep, what about `first_int[i], first_int[i+1] = first_int[i+1], first_int[i]`? I think it's not really good, but I will try to do sth easy like your way

Comment: @DuongVu: Well, with lists it is an entirely different issue, but you need to pass in the **list**, not the integers.

Comment: @DuongVu Besides, you know that Python has a built-in complex type, right?

Comment: @LennartRebebro: In fact, I dont know. Im just a newbie and do my homework to understand Python.

Comment: @DuongVu: Well, it does. I also don't understand what your code is supposed to do, so in your next question post the code, and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, it's better for me. My English is not really good but I will try later. Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

Numbers are immutable in python. His when you pass them to a function, the function works with copies of the variables. This can be tricky if you try this with mutable types like Lists. But python has this function covered with some neat syntax tricks.

```
   a, b = b, a
```

This swaps two variables with no need for any additional functions.

Comment: Numbers *are* immutable in Python. But this is completely irrelevant for this question.

Comment: Fair enough. I wanted OP to be aware that more complex functions can possibly change mutable types but not immutable types. Thus no function could inplace swap two numbers directly whereas if he passed them in a list, he could modify the list and get a functional work around. But as you pointed out, not really what he asked and I didn't really explain what I meant.